# How to extract a record in a text on string match in a file using bash

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file sample.txt as

```
=====record1
title:javabook
price:$120
author:john
path:d:
=====record2
title:.netbook
author:paul
path:f:
=====record3
author:john
title:phpbook
subject:php
path:f:
price:$150
=====record4
title:phpbook
subject:php
path:f:
price:$150
```

from this I want to split the data based on author, it should split into 2 files which contains

```
test1.txt

=====record1
    title:javabook
    price:$120
    author:john
    path:d:
=====record3
    author:john
    title:phpbook
    subject:php
    path:f:
    price:$150
```

and

```
test2.txt

=====record2
    title:.netbook
    author:paul
    path:f:
```

like the above I want to classify the main sample.txt file into sub files based on author field dynamically.

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: Do you have to do this completely using bash? I mean if you are comofortable with python or C. You could write the code for reading from *test.txt* and writing to different files in that particular language. You could then write a simple bash script for compiling the python/C code and running the executable. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

tr '\n' ' ' < sample.txt | sed 's:=====:\n=====:g' | sed 's: *$::g' >tmp1

grep "author:john" tmp1 | sed 's: :\n\t:g' > test1.txt
grep "author:paul" tmp1 | sed 's: :\n\t:g' > test2.txt

rm tmp1
```

the "tr" command replaces every newline for a space (the whole file is now 1 line)
this gets piped to "sed" which will cause every "=====" to start on a new line.
The second "sed" will delete trailing spaces.  This all is send into a temporary file. You now have 1 "record" per line.

The first "grep" will read from the temporary file and output all the records where "author" is "john", these records are piped into "sed" which replaces every space with a newline-followed-by-tab (to exactly reproduce the OP's layout) and send this to a file named test1.txt

The second grep idem for "paul" and "test2.txt"

Last action is deleting the temporary file which is no longer needed,